# How to preserve individual reports while generating a combined one using Coverage.py

Tags: python, code-coverage

I just started using Coverage.py. I have a couple of .py  scripts and I need to generate the combined report regarding their code coverage. **I also need to keep the individual report for each .py script.**
As I debug the code, I notice that for each script there is a .coverage file generated. The problem is that after I run the

`os.system("coverage combine")
 os.system("coverage report -m")
 os.system("coverage html")`

commands, the individual reports seem to go away. The combined report is generated.
Is there any way to fix this?
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Have you considered copying the individual reports before making the combined one?

Comment: Yeah, but I thought that there is some kind of Coverage.py command to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to keep the original reports. You should copy the files.

PS: subprocess is better than os.system

PPS: [Coverage.py has an API](http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.2/api.html), so you don't need to spawn processes at all.